# Redirect xsl:message to log4j

Tags: java, log4j, xslt

I am using SaxonJ to perform XSLT transformation from Java.

My XSLT files have  to output any debug/info as output since my transformation logic is complex.

Is there a way in which I can redirect  to log4j so that I can store have the transformation information in a log file?

My system already uses log4j to log output to file. I want to append the transformation debug messages as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you have already found out how to perform this. But I hope that my answer will be useful for other people.

All you need to do is implementing MessageListener interface: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/MessageListener.html

```
public class MessageListenerImpl implements MessageListener {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MessageListenerImpl.class);

    public void message(XdmNode content, boolean terminate, SourceLocator locator) {
        if (terminate) {
            logger.error(content.getStringValue());
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            logger.warn(content.getStringValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your own Message emitter. There are various interfaces to do this, see for example

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/FeatureKeys.html#MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS

or there's a simpler interface in the s9api XsltTransformer class.

Comment: Any examples or links on the usage of MESSAGE_EMITTER_CLASS. I am not able to find usages/examples online.
I believe this is how you set the Configuration - http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/Configuration.html#setMessageEmitterClass%28java.lang.String%29 but how do you instantiate the Configuration class?

Comment: There will always be a Configuration just below the surface. For example if you use JAXP you can get to it from the net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl, or if you use XQJ you can get to it from the SaxonXQDataSource.